# UIResponder's pressBegan doesn't register character press

Tags: ios, swift

I'm facing a weird issue. I overrode `func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?)` in my view to handle key presses. It works fine with character key presses. But as soon as I try to use modifier keys (cmd, shift, etc.), it stops registering the actual character key.

- Pressing character keys while holding other character keys works fine
- Pressing modifier keys while holding other modifier keys works fine
- Pressing character keys while holding modifier keys doesn't register the character keys, modifier keys are still registered. Only the first press of each character is registered, after that, I have to release the modifier, press that character key once (not registered here), that seems to reset something and then modifier + character works again once.

Here is the code:

```
class SomeView: UIView {
  override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool { true }

  init() {
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    becomeFirstResponder()
  }

  override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    print(presses.first?.key?.keyCode.rawValue, presses.count)
  }
}
```

With this action sequence:

- Press Cmd and hold it (1)
- Press z (2)
- Press z (3)
- Press z (4)
- Release Cmd (5)
- Press z (6)
- Press z (7)
- Press Cmd and hold it (8)
- Press z (9)
- Press z (10)

It will produce this output:

```
Optional(227) 1 // (1)
Optional(29) 1 // (2), (3) and (4) are lost. (5) doesn't do anything as I don't override pressEnded
Optional(29) 1 // (7), (6) is lost
Optional(227) 1 // (8)
Optional(29) 1 // (9), (10) is lost
```

Comment: Update: I tried to build for MacOS, and it actually runs fine with macOS